# Repeating **systemd[1]: Time has been changed** on syslog

Tags: 16.04, server, systemd, time, syslog

I can see following in the syslog (on ubuntu 16.04)

```
Mar 28 22:51:36 gitserv systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 5h 9min    12.773843s random time.
Mar 28 22:51:36 gitserv systemd[1]: snapd.refresh.timer: Adding 3h 24min 34.415866s random time.
Mar 28 22:51:41 gitserv systemd[1]: Time has been changed
Mar 28 22:51:41 gitserv systemd[1304]: Time has been changed
```

I have disabled both snapd.refresher.service and apt-daily.service

```
● apt-daily.service - Daily apt activities
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apt-daily.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: inactive (dead)
 Docs: man:apt(8)


● snapd.refresh.service - Automatically refresh installed snaps
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.refresh.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead)
Docs: man:snap(1)
```

I have disabled the NTP sync as well, but this continues to appear at 2-3 second intervals.

Your help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166639/how-to-disable-systemds-time-has-been-changed-message-spam-in-systemd-journal may be helpful

Comment: Thanks for the response @Mark Stosberg, above solution points to disable logging to avoid the log entry.  but it looks like apt-daily service and snapd are resetting the time set by each other, which might be the root cause.  So how can I address that issue ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Not sure if you are running your server on a Hyper-V VM though.
[/var/log/syslog 'systemd[1]: Time has been changed' message every 5 seconds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/888493/var-log-syslog-systemd1-time-has-been-changed-message-every-5-seconds/890354#890354?newreg=0c5a628a4d8a4809a9298176c94d004e)